# How to "combine" lines printed by multiple programs safely?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Suppose I want to execute multiple programs in parallel and combine their outputs to one pipe:

```
sh -c '
    (echo qqq; echo qqq2; echo qqq3)&
    (echo www; echo www2; echo www3)& 
    (echo eee; echo eee2; echo eee3)& 
  wait; wait; wait'
```

This shell approach works well for this simple case, but I expect it to fail if programs output more and longer lines in buffered way, like this (constructed):

```
qqq
qqwww
q2
qqq3www2

wwweee3

eee2
eee3
```

One of the solution I was hinted to use was `tail -f`:

```
tail -n +0 -q -f <(echo qqq; echo qqq2; echo qqq3) <(echo www; echo www2; echo www3) <(echo eee; echo eee2; echo eee3)
```

, but this is sub-optimal option: it outputs data sluggishly, it does not terminate; I see outputs not in "sleep" order, but in arguments order in this case:

```
tail -n +0 -q -f <(sleep 1; echo qqq; sleep 1; echo qqq2; echo qqq3) <(echo www; echo www2; sleep 10; echo www3) <(echo eee; sleep 4; echo eee2; echo eee3) | cat
```

I've [implemented](https://github.com/vi/fdlinecombine) a special little program for this, but believe that there should be some standard good way to do it.

How to do it using standard tools (and without `tail -f` disadvantage)?

Comment: How do you want to mix the output? Apparently you do want to mix the output since you want “sleep order” rather than “arguments order”. Is your requirement to mix the output but not the lines, i.e. to have each line printed atomically?

Comment: Linewise. All lines from all started programs should be delivered early, but without mixing inside each line.

Comment: I think the standard way of doing this is called, well, `syslog`...

Comment: Is using `syslog` not for logs, but for something custom considered OK?

Comment: This isn't any more ideal than other suggestions posted thus far, but I thought it would be worth mentioning the `-s` option for tail. e.g. `tail -f -s .1 file` will reduce the loop delay to .1 seconds from the default 1 second.

Comment: Note that this will only happen if the program writes incomplete lines. Usually programs will write complete lines, so this does not happen. If the program calls `printf("foo bar\n")`, it is not possible for something to occur in the middle. Only if it calls `printf("foo "); printf("bar\n");` can it happen.

Comment: @Patrick, In my use case input data can be high bandwidth and transferred over TCP from multiple sources, so even if all programs output lines in single syscall, lines can get mangled.

Answer (score 4):

[GNU Parallel.](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel/)

From [release notes](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7686) dated August 2013:

> `--line-buffer` will buffer output on line basis. `--group` keeps the output together for a whole job. `--ungroup` allows output to mixup with
>   half a line coming from one job and half a line coming from another
>   job. `--line-buffer` fits between these two; it prints a full line, but
>   will allow for mixing lines of different jobs.

For example:

`parallel --line-buffer <jobs`

Where `jobs` contains:

```
./long.sh
./short.sh one
./short.sh two
```

`short.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
        echo "short line $1"
        sleep .1
done
```

`long.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while true; do
        echo -n "long line with multiple write()s "
        sleep .1
        count=$((count+1))
        if [ $count -gt 30 ]; then
                count=0
                echo
        fi
done
```

Output:

```
short line one
short line two
short line one
short line two
short line one
**-snip-**
short line one
short line one
short line two
short line two
short line one
short line one
short line one
long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s long line with multiple write()s 
short line two
short line two
short line two
short line one
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution implementing locks :

```
function putlines () {
   read line || return $?
   while ! ln -s $$ lock >/dev/null 2>&1
   do
      sleep 0.05
   done
   echo "$line" 
}

function getlines () {
     while read lline
     do 
          echo "$lline"
          rm lock
     done
}

# your paralelized jobs  
(  
   job1 | putlines & 
   job2 | putlines & 
   job3 | putlines & 
   wait
) | getlines| final_processing
```

There should be a faster way to create a lock than using the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything simple, that will help you, if your lines are so long, that one program will be sent to sleep before it was able, to finish writing a line to stdout.

However, if your lines are short enough to be written entirely before process switching, and your problem is, that generating one line takes very long, you can buffer the output using read.

E.g.:

```
((./script1 | while read line1; do echo $line1; done) & \
(./script2 | while read line2; do echo $line2; done)) | doSomethingWithOutput
```

Comment: Not beautiful. Unlikely that reliable. Unlikely that performance will be good.

Comment: You're right. It's not beatiful but looks more like a dirty hack. However, I don't think thats enough to judge performance and reliability. In addition, you wanted to use 'standard tools'. So I wouldn't be suprised, if you have to accept some ugliness (in the end). But maybe someone has a more satisfactory solution.

Comment: Currently I'm satisfied with my program (linked in the question) except that it is not available in repositories thus can't be considered even a little "standard". The solution may be to trying to push it there...

Answer (score 0):

You could make a named pipe with `mkfifo`, dump all the output into the named pipe, and separately read from the named pipe for your collected data:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
job1 > /tmp/mypipe &
job2 > /tmp/mypipe &
job3 > /tmp/mypipe &

cat /tmp/mypipe > /path/to/final_output &

wait; wait; wait; wait
```

Comment: How will this protect from mangling when `job1` and `job2` output long (>4096 bytes) lines? This seems to be named pipe equivalent of the very code first example in quesion.

Comment: Very fair point.  I did not consider large-blob output despite it being called out explicitly in your question.  I am now wondering if there is not perhaps some tool that does the reverse of `tee`, which sounds like exactly what you want.  Possibly look at the internals of `syslog` or other logging tools, because they definitely aggregate output from several places into one log file.  Locking may well be the right answer, as @emmanual suggested, also.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, But I have been wondering about the same, and this is what I have come up with:

```
garbling_job | (
    while read LINE
    do
        echo $LINE
    done
) &
```

I seem to be able to start quite a few of those without having to worry about garbled output.

EDIT: As Ole suggests - You should be careful with long lines (> 4k, for details see Oles comment below)

Here is my test program

```
if [ "$1" = "go" ]
then
for i in 1 2
do
    printf 111112222222222223333
    sleep .01
    printf 3333333444444444444555555555555
    sleep .01
    printf 6666666666666667777
    sleep .01
    printf 777777788888888889999999999999999
    sleep .01
    echo
done
exit
fi

# running them in sequence is all very fine
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
do
    echo bash $0 go 
done

# now this is all garbled up
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
do
    bash $0 go &
done
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do wait; done

# using cat inbetween does not make it better
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
do
    bash $0 go | cat &
done
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do wait; done

# it does not help to use stdbuff after the thing that just printfs sporadicall
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
do
    bash $0 go | stdbuf -oL cat &
done
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do wait; done

# it does not help to use stdbuff before either - or I am not understanding stdbuff
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
do
    stdbuf -o10000 bash $0 go | stdbuf -oL cat &
echo
done
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do wait; done

# can I read - yes - they are now fine again
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
do
bash $0 go | (
    while read LINE
    do
        echo $LINE
    done
) &
echo
done
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do wait; done
```

Comment: You need to test with lines that are bigger than your page size (typically 4-8K). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P

Comment: I disagree slightly. If You have such diverse output, You may want to do something other than echo-multiplexing into a pipe altogether. For short lines like old fashioned logs and status messages, the above seems to work and is very simple.

Comment: If you already know there is a limitation to your solution, consider include that. My experience with UNIX people is that if they see a solution that works for n then they assume it will also work for n*10 - unless it is explained that there is a limit to n. If you can explain _why_ there is a limit to n and how to raise it, it is even better.